# How can I import Google Calendar events into a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-workspace, google-sheets, google-calendar

I just need rows with name, date/time, and location.

Ideally it should be done automatically every n hours or at every event added.

I found a script solution [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007649/how-to-integrate-google-spreadsheet-with-google-calendar), but is there any other way to do it besides programmatically?

Comment: Do realize that the [so] script creates calendar events. You want the opposite...

Comment: Yes, but the script is still agood starting point to develop my solution. Altough zapier seem to really cool I still prefere to damage my spreadsheet by myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is a bit old, but I thought I'd share this script by Justin Gale, that does a great job to import Google Events in Google spreadsheet, and is free: https://www.cloudbakers.com/blog/export-google-calendar-entries-to-a-google-spreadsheet

Just duplicate the Google Sheet (with script) at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkUblBlbq6UEdDVlRXVRclF1amMtYnhHX0oteExBSFE&newcopy

Then open your copy of the spreadsheet and click `Tools--Script Editor`
Replace Justin’s email address with your own (or that of your shared calendar email address) on line 23 (`var mycal =...`)
From the Script Editor Screen, click `Run--export_gcal_to_gsheet` and see the results (in the spreadsheet)

Be aware that the very first time, you will be asked to authorize the script which wants to read your calendar, and write to your spreadsheet (please grant these permissions when requested)

Optionally, you can change the dates and search criteria on line 39 (`var events =...`) It should read: `var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("August 1, 2016 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("December 1, 2016 23:59:59 CST"), {search: ''});`

The code explains the search syntax (that allows to filter by requiring or excluding some word).

Answer (score 5):

Looks like [this Zap](https://zapier.com/z/CLK/zapbook/google-calendar/google-docs/696/create-google-docs-row-google-calendar/) from [Zapier](https://zapier.com/z/7W/) should have you covered. It'll automatically check Google Calendar for you every 15 minutes or so for new events and save them to a new row in a Google Spreadsheet.

[image: Google Calendar to Google Spreadsheet]

Discloser: I'm the co-founder of this company. But I still think it's a great solution. :)

Comment: You need to disclose your affiliation, read the section about this: [faq#promotion]

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra thanks for the heads up Jacob. I've updated the post.

Comment: @Wade Although it does it's job nicely, it still would be nice if you mentioned it's a paid service now. At first sight, that wasn't obvious, and after experimenting for some time, it appears there'e a free trial time of 2 weeks, and after it costs $20-250 per month! To expensive for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Summary**

You can import the [public or secret calendar address in iCal](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648?hl=en) format with the function [`=importdata()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en).

**Example**

I created an [example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLYfOj4eoc87DPysq95i06WLH81vWnGLPBCk01vOGMc/edit?usp=sharing)

- A1: save the ical calendar address ([See your calendar (view only)](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648?hl=en))

The link should end with ".ics"

- A2: `=index(IMPORTDATA(A1),,1)`

The `index()` function removes unwanted columns. Normally, the iCal file is just one column. However, sometimes the descriptions get imported as multiple columns but I did not care for the descriptions.

- C2: `=filter($A:$A, FIND("SUMMARY",$A:$A))`

Finds the rows with a title in them.

- D2: `=filter($A:$A, FIND("DTSTART",$A:$A))`

Finds the rows with the start date and time.

- H2: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C2000,"SUMMARY:",""))`

Makes the title more readable.

- I2: `=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(DATE(mid(D2:D2000,9,4),mid(D2:D2000,13,2),mid(D2:D2000,15,2))+TIME(mid(D2:D2000,18,2),mid(D2:D2000,20,2),0),""))`

Formats the start date and time.

**Feed refresh time tip**

The iCal calendar will be cashed by the google sheet. Every so often the new data will be loaded. When you want to force a refresh than you can change the url from "https" to "http" or the other way around. This can be neatly automated with for instance the "tick box".

Answer (score 1):

I am helping to create an app that does this! (So this is kind of self-promotion)

We're called TimeNavi and you can calculate the time spent on different events in your calendar and export them to Google Sheets with any time frame you like. The downside of our app is that it doesn't do it automatically, instead it exports your calendar on demand.

Export to sheets is a premium feature at the moment but you can start a free trial for 14 days.

If you're interested you can check us out here:

[Gsuite Marketplace Info](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/timenavi/1004396435367?hl=en&pann=caw)

[TimeNavi Website](https://timenavi.com/)

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! Thanks for stating your affiliation, however please note that there's a [soft limit](/help/promotion) to how much self-promotion is allowed.